# Xcode 6 Storyboard crashing when scrolling to particular ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have upgraded to X-code 6.0.1 and now in Storyboard, a couple of viewControllers are missing.. when I try to Scroll to them it stops just before them, X-Code freezes and I have to Force it shut. I have validated the XML and that seems fine.

Not sure what this might be has anyone had any similar issues?

Comment: I've had issues with opening nib files. If I'm on a nib file I have to go to a code file before opening another nib or Xcode may crash.

Comment: I had the same issue and finally find a way to suppress the Xcode Freeze. Might not be a best way but sure it helps. Select your story board and dont scroll down instead of that delete the view controller and create a new one which help me....

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue and was able to fix by deleting the **xcuserdata** folder.  It's worth a try:

1. Close Xcode
2. Right click on your **.xcodeproj** and **Show Package Contents**
3. Delete the contents of **xcuserdata**
4. Try again.

---

Edit:

Another workaround I found was to never switch between .xib or .storyboards directly. Xcode doesn't crash if I open a source file in between.

This was written for Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: I am facing the same problem but still I am unable to Figure out the solution Any one please help me