# Xcode 6 Getting crashed while opening story board which uses Popover Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6, segue

My xcode is recently updated to 6.0.1. In my application i used a popover segue actually for a test purpose. After that the xcode is getting crash continuously. I have re-installed xcode again but no result. Getting crashed again after it opened. Please give me solution to overcome this..
[image]

Comment: LOL'd at the crash log description *"This shouldn't happen"*... Sorry, wish I could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I restored Xcode using the command

> defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

in the Terminal.app

That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26110269/546719

Xcode keeps some UI state in that folder and that seems to be creating some inconsistencies that lead to crashes and/or infinite loops.